# Limit using Taylor expansion : which term do we expand?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I want to check the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\text{exp}\left (\frac{n}{2}\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )\right )}$ using the Taylor expansion.

I have done the following:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\text{exp}\left (\frac{n}{2}\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )\right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\text{exp}\left (\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )^{\frac{n}{2}}\right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )^{\frac{n}{2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left (\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2+1}\right )^{\frac{n}{2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(n-1)^n}{\left (n^2+1\right )^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$

For which term do we have to write the Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}=1-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}$$

then we can start by by first order Taylor's expansion for $\log(1+x)$ to obtain

$$\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )=\ln\left (1-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\right )=-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

then

$$\text{exp}\left (\frac{n}{2}\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )\right )=\text{exp}\left( -\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}+O\left(\frac1{n}\right)\right)\to e^{-1}$$

then in this case a first order expansion suffices.

In general there is not a method to determine *a priori* which order we need to expand to but after some practice it becomes relatively easy for standard limits.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the logarithm
$$
\ln\left(\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right)=\ln\left (1-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\right)=-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}+\ldots
$$

Comment: Ok! So we get that \begin{equation*}\text{exp}\left (\frac{n}{2}\ln\left (\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2+1}\right )\right )\approx \text{exp}\left (\frac{n}{2}\left (-\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\right )\right )=\text{exp}\left (-\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\right )\end{equation*} and if $n\rightarrow +\infty$ then we get $e^{-1}$ , right?

Comment: @MaryStar: yes, it is right